# Implement Batch Export in the Jasper reports server to get the landscape and portrait in a single report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I am trying to implement a batch export similar to one [here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html) (as in the link) in jasper reports.
Please give pointers.

**What I have:**
 1. A Portrait Template
 2. A Landscape Template
 3. Order in which I need to generate the reports
 4. Same Bean Datasource with filter queries for each template to fill

**What I need:**
Generate the reports separately and merge all the generated JasperPrint objects and tweak the Page Nos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are generating the reports and then merging it, current page number and total pages are available only during the export, based on the number of reports you merge. We solved a similar issue using [generic elements](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/genericelement/index.html). You need to write your custom logic to handle the page number inside the handler you create.

Comment: Thnx for the pointer. I have overridden the JRPdfExporter's exportGenericElement() method and added a JRPrintText which shows the merged jasper print object's total page size.

Comment: Hi Cid..I've the same problem..can you post the pseudo code to add JRPrintText.

Comment: Balaji Paulrajan: pls send me the pseudo code to how to achieve using generic elements...

Comment: Hi TP_JAVA, I dont have the code now. Your mail id is not in the profile. so send me a mail. I will let you know the approach we took.

Answer (score 0):

My report page 1 (jr1) is portrait and page 2 (jr2) landscape.

```java
JasperReport jr1 = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(...);
JasperReport jr2 = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(...);

JREmptyDataSource ds = new JREmptyDataSource(1);
JasperPrint print1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr1, new HashMap(), ds);

ds.moveFirst();

JasperPrint print2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr2, new HashMap(), ds);
List l = new ArrayList();

l.add(print1);
l.add(print2);

JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, l);
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, SAVE_LOCATION);
exp.exportReport();
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem with this approach. The page numbers will not be in sequence. For example if there are 12 pages in the first template the first page of the second page will not show Page 13 instead it will display Page 1

Answer (score 0):

**This might work for page number issue:**

private static void mergeAndNumber() throws IOException, DocumentException 
{

```
    PdfReader readerOne = new PdfReader("c:\file_one.pdf"«»);



    // we retrieve the total number of pages

    int nOne = readerOne.getNumberOfPages();



    PdfReader readerTwo = new PdfReader("c:\file_two.pdf"«»);



    // we retrieve the total number of pages

    int nTwo = readerTwo.getNumberOfPages();



    int totalPages = (nOne + nTwo);

    System.out.println("Total number of pages: " + (nOne + nTwo));



    Rectangle psize = readerOne.getPageSize(1);

    float widthPort = psize.width();

    float heightPort = psize.height();



    // step 1: creation of a document-object

    Document document = new Document(psize, 50, 50, 50, 50);

    // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:\file_combined.pdf"«»));



    document.open();

    // step 4: we add content

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();



    PdfImportedPage importPage = null;



    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    float pageNumXPos = widthPort;

    float pageNumYPos = heightPort;

    for (int i = 1; i <= nOne; i++) {

        document.newPage();

        importPage = writer.getImportedPage(readerOne, i);

        cb.addTemplate(importPage, 0,0);



        cb.moveTo(400, 40);         

        cb.beginText();

        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);

        //cb.showText("Page " + i  + " of " + totalPages);          

        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "Page " + i  + " of " + totalPages, pageNumXPos - 45, pageNumYPos - 55, 0);

        cb.endText();

    }



    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());



    for (int i = 1; i <= nTwo; i++) {

        document.newPage();

        importPage = writer.getImportedPage(readerTwo, i);

        cb.addTemplate(importPage, 0,0);



        cb.moveTo(400, 40);        

        cb.beginText();

        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);

        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "Page " + (nOne + i)  + " of " + totalPages, pageNumYPos - 20, pageNumXPos - 60, 0);         

        cb.endText();

    }



    document.close();        

}
```

Comment: I didnt wanna manipulate at the iText level. Thnx for your suggestion